# Grabbing two different sections of a list

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Using `Scikit Learn` I have built some basic sentiment classifiers in Python. I am now trying to evaluate using a cross-validation technique. I have my dataset containing 100,000 positive and negative tweets called `training_data`.

Each time I need to grab a block of 20,000 from the overall set for testing, and then use the remaining 180,000 for training. The problem I have is when the block is not at either end, how do I just get the data either side of that block?

I have tried doing something like

```
training_data.data[:20000] + training_data.data[40000:]
```

but it says

> operands cannot be broadcast together with different shapes

however I was under the impression that the `dataset.data` was just a list.

As requested here is an example of the output from training_data.data[1:10]:

`["@karoliiinem i'm personally following the next 300 people that will follow --&
gt; @omgfantasy  rt once you're done so i'd know ?\n", '@kristensaywha i know  s
tupid people\n', 'i might be going shopping tomorrow at the beach ) i hope so\n'
, '@_sophieallam cannae wait for a 5 hour train journey \n', 'wifey needs a hug
\n', "i'm scared to drive to daytona with this car \n", "@xxiluvdahviexx  i'm so
 sorry\n", "@chooselogoism that sucks i can't see w/o my glasses at all\n", 'x f
actor \n']`

I guess I am looking for some kind of operation on a list in which you can grab all the data except for a specified slice?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include a print out of `training_data.data[0:10]` (for example) so we can see the type? Or print `training_data.data` and post the first few lines.

Comment: The example output is not clear to me. It doesn't seem to contain 10 objects.

Comment: Oh, it is actually not in markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sklearn.cross_validation.KFold` generates these folds for you.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
cv = KFold(180000, 9)
```

returns an iterator which yields training and test indices at each step. If your classifier is called `your_classifier`, your data (tweets) is `X` and your targets (sentiments) is `y`, then you can use `sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score` in order to obtain scores across all the folds:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
scores = cross_val_score(your_classifier, X, y, cv=cv, scoring= ...)
```

where `scoring` is a very important thing to look at. If you use a naive scorer, such as accuracy, which counts correct predictions, your classes must be balanced, or you must be aware of the fact that your estimator may just be predicting the more frequent class. In case you want to balance your classes, you may want to take a look at `sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold` ([doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html)) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `cross_validation` module, which has many scenarios you can use, one is `k-fold`.

I'm copy pasting from `sklearn` manual page [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html):

```
>>> from sklearn import cross_validation
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> kf = cross_validation.KFold(4, n_folds=2)
>>> len(kf)
2
>>> print(kf)
sklearn.cross_validation.KFold(n=4, n_folds=2)
>>> for train_index, test_index in kf:
...    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
...    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
...    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
TRAIN: [2 3] TEST: [0 1]
TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2 3]
```